# Rails 5 ActiveRecord::ForbiddenAttributesError with Strong Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attributes

I am attempting to add nested comments to my forum project. These comments have a polymorphic association with 2 different types of forum post (Artwork and Post). I am following this tutorial: 
http://www.tweetegy.com/2013/04/create-nested-comments-in-rails-using-ancestry-gem/

Currently when I sumbit my comments form I receive this error:

'ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in Posts::CommentsController#create'

The line in question is within the create method of my comments controller:

```
def create
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment]) # This is the line that causes the error
    # @comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params)--when changed to this, the submit button simply stops submitting anything
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully created comment"
            redirect_to @commentable
    else
        flash[:error] = "Error adding comment"
    end
end
```

The rest of my comments_controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    @parent_id = params.delete(:parent_id)
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = Comment.new(:parent_id => @parent_id, :commentable_id => @commentable.id, :commentable_type => @commentable.class.to_s)
end

def create
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment]) # This is the line that causes the error
    # @comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params)--when changed to this, the submit button simply stops submitting anything
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully created comment"
            redirect_to @commentable
    else
        flash[:error] = "Error adding comment"
    end
end

def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Your Comment was successfully deleted"
end

def upvote
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
end

def downvote
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.downvote_by current_user
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path) #maybe change to - :back returns you to the same page - upvotes/downvotes can be on index and show pages
end

private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:parent_id, :comment)
end 

def find_commentable
  params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
          return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
      end
  end
  nil
end
end
```

Comments form:

```
= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f|
= f.hidden_field :parent_id
= f.text_area :comment
= f.submit
```

Comment Model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_votable
  has_ancestry
  attr_accessor :content, :parent_id, :commentable_id, :commentable_type
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I am fairy new to ruby so I am not certain what I am doing wrong...  this has stumped me for ages as I cannot tell which attributes are being passed and forbidden.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: here is the development log for creating a comment

Started POST "/posts/5/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-06 14:35:21 +0000
Processing by Posts::CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"NQ25DUzZ0di2L+rdARO8jEmkb/flm1hEAO7tLj331CbTwJUPGarzBTcTR+D0oV1xExwLVZ7bjrheVm1sGqh7dg==", "comment"=>{"parent_id"=>"", "comment"=>"comment test"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "post_id"=>"5"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mPost Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mCACHE Post Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:12:in `create'

Comment: You’re returning nil from the find_commentable method. Is that what it is supposed to return?

Comment: Check your development log and show us full params hash that is passed when you submit the form.

Comment: I have added the development log at the end of the post